# Hook or callback when wp_nav_menu() has completed

Tags: menus, walker

I am modifying the $output of `wp_nav_menu()` using a custom walker, and I need to run a function after the final closing `</ul>` of the entire menu. I can only see the following methods available:

```
start_lvl()    // Runs when a child menu is started
end_lvl()      // Runs when a child menu is completed
start_el()     // Runs when a menu item is started
end_el()       // Runs when a menu item is completed
```

I can't find anything that runs when the top level menu is completed. Is this possible?

Comment: What type of function do you need to run and why? If you just need to output something additional, you may be able to use the `items_wrap` argument when you call `wp_nav_menu()` to output it.

Comment: Hi, I need to output markup that will have been dynamically generated and stored in a private property of the custom menu walker.